# Filter a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ado.net, datagridview, rowfilter

I'm trying to filter a DataGridView, the DataSource is a DataSet.

So I'm using the following line to filter the grid:

```
DataTable dt = (dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0];
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CustomerName = 'My Customer'";
```

However the grid doesn't get filtered and all the rows are still displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: This has not fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebind the grid then. I would suggest you calling the function data get the dataset and then apply the rowfilter:

```
var view=GetDataSet().Tables[0].DefaultView
view.RowFilter = "CustomerName = 'My Customer'";
dataGridViewMain.DataSource=view;
dataGridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Otherwise you might have to do this:

```
var view=(dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].DefaultView
view.RowFilter = "CustomerName = 'My Customer'";
dataGridViewMain.DataSource=view;
dataGridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there no way of doing this without rebinding the DataSource? I want the filter to be above the grid and get the user to type in there filter text. But when the user removes the filter I want the original datasource set without going back to the database. Thanks

Comment: To set the original datasource back set RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.OriginalRows

Answer (score 1):

When you are binding your controls, are you binding them to the DefaultView or to the DataTable? Binding to the DataTable will never show the RowFilter you have against the DefaultView.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the rowstate filter to DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent.Also accept the changes for datatable and rebind the datagrid.

```
(dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
dataGridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I've tried the following code:

(dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Asset_No = 'Base Class 5'";
(dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].DefaultView.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
(dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
                                   
But there is no DataBind Method. Any chance of a full example? Thanks

Comment: dataGridViewMain.DataBind() not there??

Comment: Not, it's not there. I have DataBindings but not DataBind

Comment: strange.is your control "asp:GridView"?

Comment: No, it's a C# DataGridView (from System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)

Comment: Sorry my mistake.In that case you have to specify the datasource for the control again as givn in the second example of answer above.

Comment: No this doesn't work. My code is now like the following: 

var view = (dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = "Asset_No = 'Base Class 5'";
                dataGridViewMain.DataSource=view;

Is this what you meant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10039/discussion-between-user1131661-and-krishnanunni-jeevan)

Comment: try filters:  BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
           source1.DataSource = (dataGridViewMain.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[0].DefaultView;
           source1.Filter = "Asset_No = 'Base Class 5'";

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm all sorted now.